# Cannot add 'Page Title' and 'Main Content' blocks to panel

Tags: 8, panels

Configuration:

- Drupal 8.1.5
- Panels 8.x-3.0-beta4
- Page Manager 8.x-1.0-alpha23
- Layout plugin 8.x-1.0-alpha22
- Panelizer 8.x-3.0-alpha2

When I create a Panel variant for `/node/{node}` with Page Manager, I can add field blocks, like

- `entity_field:node:title`
- `entity_field:node:body`

These get rendered.

However, if I add blocks

- CORE / Page Title (`page_title_block`)
- SYSTEM / Main page content (`system_main_block`)

these render to nothing.
Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after I found some more info.

This is indeed a bug, hopefully to be fixed soon: https://www.drupal.org/node/2626090